# How to delete a thumbnail programmatically from galley after deleting an image?

Tags: android, gallery, thumbnails, android-sdcard, image-gallery

I am developing an app which hides images. I am able to delete images but gallery won't refresh itself & displays the thumbnail of an image which is hidden by my app. I am using

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
        Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

this code & it works upto an extent. But the main thing is that it first unmount & remount the SDCard which is time + resource consuming. Is there any another way which can instantly refresh the gallery without remounting the sdcard. One more thing I have also tried this code.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
        getBaseContext(),
        new String[]{ src.toString() },
        null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            }
        );
```

And it is also not satisfying.

Comment: Do you want to hide them (i.e. put a `.nomedia` file in the folder) or you want to delete them (gone forever)?

Comment: I have also same problem, if any one get the solution, please help

Comment: have you found any solution fr this ?

Comment: dd you find any solution?